# How to organize an xcode project that uses SVN but depends on libraries which use Git?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, svn, version-control

We have a project that utilizes SVN for source control, as necessitated by company policy. The project depends on about a dozen external libraries, which are found publicly on github. Until now, we've simply been downloading a zip file of each library we use, then add the source code directly to our project, but this is bad practice for obvious reasons.

We would like the ability to update the external libraries, and use them in other projects as well. Additionally, we will modify some of the libraries, and would like to be able to merge in changes as the main branch of the library updates.

How would one go about setting up this kind of project? I had thought about forking each git library, but I'm not sure how I would add the dependency to xcode and have SVN properly include the libraries. I've also looked at cocoapods, but if I'm not mistaken, they seem to be more for read-only dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Use a python based build system and install pysvn and one of the python git bindings - your build system can then handle (inter-)dependencies cleanly.

Comment: Changing the SVN system is not an option. Also: wut.